# Mapping two List<> into HashMap

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I have a two List **List of ColumnIndexMapping and other is List of String**

One list contains an Object of a class. Structure is look like below-

```
public class ColumnIndexMapping {

    private int index;
    private String columnname;

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }
    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }
    public String getColumnname() {
        return columnname;
    }
    public void setColumnname(String columnname) {
        this.columnname = columnname;
    }
}
```

Now I have to make a Map using both List. I have to read only those indexes from second list (List of String) for which we have index property in first list. like below -

```
List<ColumnIndexMapping> colMapList =  [
   {
     "index": 0,
     "columnname": "accountname"
   },
   {
     "index": 2,
     "columnname": "source"
   },{
     "index": 4,
     "columnname": "customField13"
   } ]

List<String> secondList = {"Nitin","India","1234","fnf","qwerty"}


Output would be -> 

HashMap<String,String> outputHashmap = 
{
"accountname":"Nitin",
"source":"1234",
"customField13":"qwerty"

}
```

tried approach with Java7

```
Map<String, String> output = new HashMap<>();
for (ColumnIndexMapping colMap: colMapList) {
    output.put(colMap.getColumnname(), secondList .get(colMap.getIndex()));
}
```

Now what is the best way to doing this in Java8.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's not how you define `List` and `Map` in Java. Please, post the code that compiles. And, yes, you haven't tried anything. Wha would be your approach in Java 7?

Comment: @Jason I tried using Java7 approach. simply iterate both list using for loop and then do the logic but i want to achieve this using Java8

Comment: why you have downgraded this question, I know the solution using java7 but i want to get resolve this using Java8.

Comment: I haven't downvoted. However, my advice would be, start simple and optimise only if necessary. Take a look at my answer. I've taken a pretty simple approach.

Comment: @nitintyagi I downvoted. You've shown no effort (put a POJO class, and two JSON snippets into Java code which made it invalid). You didn't show how you would solve the problem by the standard means, either. I am open to upvote as soon as you edit the question.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I agree with you point that i have not posted whatever i have tried but I already asked in question about Java8 approach.  Now i have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for Java 8 stream-based approach specifically, the following would do.

```
Map<String, String> outputMap = colMapList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(ColumnIndexMapping::getColumnname, 
                    (colMap) -> secondList.get(colMap.getIndex())));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have populated the `colMapList` and `secondList` correctly, the conversion code is relatively simple:

```
List<ColumnIndexMapping> colMapList = ...; // assumed this is populated correctly
List<String> secondList = ...;             // assumed this is populated correctly

Map<String, String> output = new HashMap<>();
for (ColumnIndexMapping mapping : colMapList) {
    output.put(mapping.getColumnname(), secondList.get(mapping.getIndex()));
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you've already checked there will be enough entries in the `secondList` to populate the elements specified by the `colMapList`.